# Highlight group in `.vim/after/ftplugin` not highlighting patterns

Tags: highlight, ftplugin

While highlight group in `.vimrc` highlights patterns just fine, highlight groups in `.vim/after/ftplugin` folder does not seem to do anything. Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal, you are not using the correct directory. See [`:h mysyntaxfile-add`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile-add):

```
If you are mostly satisfied with an existing syntax file, but would like to
add a few items or change the highlighting, follow these steps:

1. Create your user directory from 'runtimepath', see above.

2. Create a directory in there called "after/syntax".  For Unix: >
    mkdir ~/.config/nvim/after
    mkdir ~/.config/nvim/after/syntax

3. Write a Vim script that contains the commands you want to use.  For
   example, to change the colors for the C syntax: >
    highlight cComment ctermfg=Green guifg=Green

4. Write that file in the "after/syntax" directory.  Use the name of the
   syntax, with ".vim" added.  For our C syntax: >
    :w ~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/c.vim

That's it.  The next time you edit a C file the Comment color will be
different.  You don't even have to restart Vim.
```

See [`:h mysyntaxfile-replace`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile-replace) if you want to completely replace an existing syntax file.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. Didn't understand where to look in the help file. Related question (don't want to ask a separate question for this): Is there a simple way to toggle a highlighing group? Couldn't find anything in the help file.

Comment: These highlights will go away if I happen to source `.vimrc` again on a file, right? That's also normal?